# Best way to use populate string with dictionary keys + values + join values

Tags: python, dictionary, join

I have a dictionary with keys and values. I need to populate the following openssl command with those key:value pairs.

```
cmd = 'openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ${CN}.key -out ${CN}.csr -subj \
"/{0}={1}/{2}={3}/{4}={5}/{6}={7}/{8}={9}/{10}={11}"'.format()
```

I was thinking about perhaps looping over the dictionary.

```
>>> for k, v in dict.items():
...     print("{0}={1}".format(k,v))
...
C=US
CN=test.domain.net
L=New York City
O=Company Inc.
S=NY
OU=Company Inc.
```

But I'm not certain how to join them with '/' so that they don't appear on new lines.

1. Is this the best approach to be using?
2. If so, how can I join the new lines into one line (so that they won't include \n in the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join them with `str.join()` using `/` as a delimiter:

```
"/".join(["{0}={1}".format(k, v) for k, v in d.items()])
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {"C": "US", "CN": "test.domain.net", "L": "New York City"}
>>> "/".join(["{0}={1}".format(k, v) for k, v in d.items()])
'C=US/CN=test.domain.net/L=New York City'
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.